# Computational Complexity of 3SAT variant with additional restrictions on variables/clauses

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given a 3SAT problem with the additional constraints that:

1. No clause or set of clauses is the 3SAT instance is '*redundant*'. Thus, this 3SAT cannot eliminate any clauses.
2. For any/every clause, the triplet of 3 variables in it are guranteed to occur in at least 1 other clause.

What is the computational complexity of this 3SAT variant?

**Redundant Clause** - A clause is redundant if its elimination from the problem does not change the set of valid solutions of the problem. For eg: $a+b+c=1,a+b=1,a+c=1$. The first clause is redundant here as it does not affect the set of valid solutions of this problem.

Comment: anyone with any ideas please?